$D_1, D_2$ are division rings, prove that if $M_r(D_1)$ is isomorphic to $M_s(D_2)$, then $D_1 \cong D_2$ and $r=s$

$D_1, D_2$ are division rings, prove that if $M_r(D_1)$ is isomorphic to $M_s(D_2)$, then $D_1 \cong D_2$ and $r=s$

To be specific, $M_r(D_1)$ is $r\times r$ matices. And I think that the isomorphism of $M_r(D_1)$ and $M_s(D_2)$ here is ring isomorphism.
I think $M_r(D_1)\cong \mathrm{End}_{D_1}(V_1)$, if $V_1$ is a $D_1$-vector space and $\mathrm{dim}V=r$. Similarly, $M_s(D_2)\cong \mathrm{End}_{D_2}(V_2)$. And I have proved before that $\mathrm{End}_{\tilde{D_1}}(V_1)\cong D_1$, where $\tilde{D_1}=\mathrm{End}_{D_1}(V_1)$. But I cannot prove that $\mathrm{End}_{\tilde{D_1}}(V_1)\cong \mathrm{End}_{\tilde{D_2}}(V_2)$.
Many thanks in advance!

Try to prove that $V_i$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) simple module of $\tilde{D}_i$.

Could you please write an answer? @CaptainLama

This proposition is related to Morita Theory and rounds out the Wedderburn-Artin Theorem.
Wedderburn-Artin Theorem. Any semisimple ring is a direct product of matrix algebras over division rings.
Definition (Morita Equivalence). Two rings $R$ and $S$ are called Morita equivalent if their categories of modules are equivalent.
(Having equivalent categories of left modules implies having equivalent categories of right modules, so we needn't specify left or right. There is an equivalent definition of Morita equivalence involving the $2$-category of bimodules which is also worth checking out.)
Proposition I. If $D$ is a division ring, the simple $M_n(D)$-module $D^n$ is unique up to equivalence and all others are direct sums of copies of it.
Proof. Suppose $M$ is an $M_n(D)$-module. We can write $M=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n e_{ii} M$, where $e_{ij}=[\delta_{ij}]$ (cf. Peirce decomposition). Recall the permutation matrix $P_\pi$ (for $\pi\in S_n$) is characterized by $P_\pi e_i=e_{\pi(i)}$. Pick $1\le i,j\le n$ and $\pi$ such that $\pi(i)=j$. Then multiplication by $P_\pi$ furnishes a $D$-module isomorphism $e_{ii}M\cong e_{jj}M$ since $P_\pi e_{ii}M=e_{jj}P_\pi M=e_{jj}M$ and $P_\pi$ is invertible ($P_\pi^{-1}=P_{\pi^{-1}}$). Writing $e_{11}M\cong D^m$ with a $D$-basis, we get $D$-bases of all $e_{ii}M$s by applying $P_\pi$s, then we can check the resulting $D$-vector space isomorphism $M\cong (D^n)^m$ is one of $M_n(D)$-modules.
Corollary I. $M_n(D)$ is Morita equivalent to $D$ for any $n\ge1$.
A $D$-module $D^m$ becomes the $M_n(D)$-module $D^m\oplus\cdots D^m\cong (D^n)^m$ and an $M_n(D)$-module $M$ becomes the $D$-module $e_{11}M$; these can be checked to create an equivalence of categories.
Proposition II. ${\rm End}_{M_n(D)}(D^n)\cong D$ (the copy of $D$ consisting of scalar matrices in $M_n(D)$).
Proof. Suppose $\phi$ is an intertwiner. For $i\ne j$ we have $e_{ii}\phi(e_j)=\phi(e_{ii}e_j)=0$ hence $\phi(e_j)=\lambda_j e_j$. If $\pi(i)=j$ then $\phi(P_\pi e_i)=P_\pi \phi(e_j)$ yields $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$, hence $\phi(x)=x\lambda$ for all $x\in D^n$ for some $\lambda\in D$.
Corollary II. If $M_r(D_1)\cong M_s(D_2)$ then $D_1\cong D_2$ and $r=s$.
Proof. First, $D_1\cong{\rm End}_{M_r(D_1)}(D_1^r)\cong{\rm End}_s(D_2^s)\cong D_2$. Second, $r=\dim_{D_1}(D_1^r)=\dim_{D_2}(D_2^s)=s$.
